# p:commandButton not updating other component on click

Tags: primefaces

I'm using primefaces for my front end with java as backing bean. I have a textarea with a clear button attached to it, followed by a selectMenu. When the textarea is not empty, I want my selectMenu disabled, however when the textArea is cleared with the button, I can't seem to get it to update the selectMenu so that it becomes enabled is again. However when the textarea is manually cleared, it updates my selectMenu.

Here is my code:

```html
<p:outputPanel>
   <div class="ui-grid-col-3">
      <p:inputTextarea id="containerNums" cols="60" rows="3">
         <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" immediate="true" update="containerSection">
      </p:inputTextarea >
   </div>
</p:outputPanel>
   <div class="ui-grid-col-3">
      <p:commandButton type="button"
         value="x"
         onclick="clearTextArea(containerNums)"
         update="containerType"/>
   </div>
<p:outputPanel>
   <p:selectOneMenu id="containerType"
   value="containerType"
   disabled="#{myBean.containerNums != null}">
</p:outputPanel>
```

Any ideas on what to change to achieve my desired result?

Comment: Hi, start by creating a [mcve] and narrow things down

Comment: Effectively you imply (without explicitly mentioning) that calling `clearTextArea(containerNums)` from the browser console it works! But I'm sure you tried that and it is indeed working.

Comment: yes it works, my actual code has a lot more going on but I tried to simplify as much as possible

Comment: It is not about simplifying alone, it is always about [mcve] there isoo much in your code that might either be a typo or code missing. And with the code as it is I cannot imagine calling the javascript from the cinsole works

Comment: The ajax of your textarea is different from the buttons' ajax in that it processes itself only (@this) while the button processes the entire form. (@form) And there is the immediate="true" thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not set/updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value)